# Sort Vector with string and int pair

Tags: c++, stl

#### cmp

`bool cmp(const pair<string, long> &p1, const pair<string, long> &p2){

    if(p1.second!=p2.second)

        return p1.second < p2.second;

    return strcmp(p1.first.c_str(),p2.first.c_str());
}`

Hi all,

I'm trying to sort the `vector` based on the `second` element of the `pair`. If the `second` elements of the pair are equal, then I compare the `first` elements of the `pair`.

I'm using the above code to sort a `vector` containing `string` and `int` `pair`. I'm invoking the sorting function using `sort_heap(vector.begin(),vector.end(),cmp);`. But this doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: thanks. Will do that. I'm New to stack overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `operator<` for the strings:

```
bool cmp(const pair<string, long> &p1, const pair<string, long> &p2)
{
    if(p1.second!=p2.second)
        return p1.second < p2.second;
    return p1.first < p2.first;
}
```

strcmp returns a negative number if the first is "less than" the second (and that's all you care about), 0 if they are equal, and a positive number if the second is less than the first.  So, if you wanted to use strcmp, you would do it like this:

```
return strcmp(p1.first.c_str(), p2.first.c_str()) < 0;
```

But I don't see why you would do that.